# Where is mono.unix.native

Tags: c#, windows, linux, mono

I have inherited a C# web app (and web services) which is being compiled on Windows and run on Mono on a Linux box.  I need to do some file permissions magic, which looks like it involves including the assembly:
mono.unix.native.

So, can I reference this on my windows box, and, if so, where is it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Mono.Unix.Native` is a namespace. The assembly where it's located is named `Mono.Posix.dll`.

I *think* it's shipped with Mono for Windows - even if it's unlikely to be used there.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I added the Mono.Podix.dll, which is installed with Mono on Windows.  All happy now.  I also got the file permissions to work!

Answer (score 3):

Your dealing with some low level Mono classes. I think you need to link to Mono.  check this.

> > The Mono.Unix.Native namespace contains low-level wrapper classes, structures, and enumerations which are accessible from the Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall and Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib classes, which are a low-level wrappers over ANSI C, POSIX and Unix system calls and library functions.

http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.Unix.Native